# What defines a regex section to be replaced in preg_replace()?

Tags: php, regex

I just started with PHP regular expressions. I understand how to read and write them (I need my book though because I haven't memorized any pattern symbols). I really want to use RegExp for BB Code on my site, using `preg_replace`.

I understand the parameters, but what I don't understand is what *defines* what is to be replaced in the pattern? What I have so far:

```
preg_replace('/(\[url=http:\/\/.*\])/','<a href="$1">$2</a>',"[url=http://google.com]");
```

Now, I know it's probably not the best "security" wise, I just want to get something to work. I match the entire string... so I get a link that looks like `mysite/[url=http://google.com]`.

I read over the PHP manual on it, but I still have a headache trying to absorb and comprehend something:

- What defines what is replaced in the string because of the pattern?
- What TELLS me what my $1 and $2 and so on are?

I don't even know what they are called. Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: normal that you don't understand nothing the pattern is false.

Comment: Hmmm? There is a match, if that's what you're saying there isn't...

The WHOLE string is matched, so I get an <a> tag with the URL and text '[url=http://google.com]'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same replacement without errors:

```
$BBlink = '[url=http://google.com]';

$pattern = '~\[url=(http://[^] ]+)]~';
$replacement = '<a href="$1">$1</a>';
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $BBlink);
```

explanations:

1) pattern

```
~       # pattern delimiter
\[      # literal opening square bracket
url=
(       # first capturing group
http://
[^] ]+  # all characters that are not ] or a space one or more times
)       # close the capturing group
]       # literal closing square bracket
~       # pattern delimiter
```

2) replacement

`$1` refer to the first capturing group

Alternative: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bbcode-create.php, see the first example.

Comment: And this pattern delimiter...Is that what gives you your $1, your $2...etc.?

Comment: So () define capture groups, and THOSE are your values to be replaced!

Oh yes. Thank you very much!

Comment: @RickyYoder: No, it is just to delimit the pattern instead of `/`, it is more easy to use `~` or `#` as pattern delimiters because this avoid to escape all the slashes.

Comment: @RickyYoder: yes parenthesis define the capture groups

Comment: +1, good stuff. You can also define non-capturing subgroups with `(?:)`, with the pattern you require after the colon. This can be handy to define a sub-section whilst turning the default capturing behaviour off.

Comment: Okay, so what if I wanted to allow the https protocol as well?

Wouldn't (http|https) be a capture group as well?

Comment: @RickyYoder: It will, but read the precedent comment or try `https?`. And take a look at this site. (a long look)

Comment: Oh! NON-capturing subgroups! Okay, I got this now! Thank you so much!